# Is it okay for a recommendation letter to be written by a professor in a different area of expertise than the target PhD?

Tags: recommendation-letter

If I am going to apply for a Ph.D. in Computer Science, with a specialization in programming languages, is it okay to use a recommendation letter from other areas of Computer Science, say cryptography?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no rule against this unless it is explicitly stated in the conditions for application. Assuming that the person in question knows you and your research potential well (or say better than others who you could've asked), this should be fine.

Note that it cannot be said in general how recommendation letters are used when assessing applications as this hugely depends on the admission process, which differs between universities, countries, subject areas, and the people who make the decisions.

Recommendation letters may or may not play an important role in the process (I think they shouldn't, but unfortunately I have seen it happening), so it is a good idea to arrange for letters of people who can write something informative. This usually means that they know well how you work and about your academic potential. In principle such people can be found outside the area where you apply, but chances are that a certain connection should exist, otherwise the commission (or whoever makes the decision) may think that the experiences of the writer with you may not be relevant. However in my view the connection can be rather loose; the skills required for cryptography are not totally different from those required in theoretical computer science (as far as I know what I'm talking about here), so I don't see a problem there.

Also it may help if somebody in the commission knows the writer or their work (at least if this is in a positive way), and chances for this are bigger in the same area, but neither are they 100% there nor 0% if the writer comes from a different field, so this is generally something the student can't make sure. It is rather something of a random experiment from the student's point of view (which is one of the reasons why I think recommendation letters shouldn't be a major aspect of making admission decisions).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is fine.  More important than the academic specialty of the referee is what they can say about your skills and experience and your research potential in your area of interest.